# Mysql get the offset of row

Tags: mysql

comment table

```
+------+----------+
| id   | comment  | 
+------+----------+
|    1 | foo      |
|    2 | bar      |
|    3 | foobar   |
+------+----------+
```

replay table

```
+------+----------+------------+
| id   | replay   |comment_id  |
+------+----------+------------+
|    1 | replay1  | 1          |
|    2 | replay2  | 2          |
|    3 | replay3  | 1          |
+------+----------+------------+

SELECT
  `comment`.`comment`,
  `comment`.`id`,
  (SELECT `replay`.`replay` FROM `replay`
   WHERE `replay`.`comment_id` = `comment`.`id`
   ORDER BY `replay`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1) AS `replay`
FROM `comment`
```

the result will be

```
+----------+------+---------+
| comment  | id   | replay  |
+----------+------+---------+
|    foo   | 1    |replay3  |
|    bar   | 2    |replay2  |
|    off   | 3    |         |
+------+----------+---------+
```

How can I get the position (offset) of the replay3, expected it to be 2

> replay1  offset it 1, replay2 offset is 1 and replay3 offset is 2

Comment: By offset do you mean the position in the table? If you don't `ORDER BY` the position will be unpredictable. Assuming you mean a chronological position, you need to add a `DATETIME` column. The ID is not always a sequencial / chronological identifier.

Comment: @DanFromGermany no not chronological  i need the offset of the replay i get it

Comment: is the "replay" value always "replayX" ? Then you should just not insert "replay" but only the number.

Comment: @DanFromGermany no its any text .. now the repaly1 and replay3 for comment (1)  and replay (2) its for comment (2) i just want the offset of replay group by comment_id so replay1 and reaply3 offset will be 1,2
and offset of replay2 will be 1 this what i want but how can i get it ?

Answer (score 0):

I got your idea now. You don't mean any offset. You  mean the number (amount) of comments per replay.

Here we go:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS amount
FROM replays
GROUP BY comment_id
```

In your existing query I'd use a `JOIN` instead of a subselect..

```
SELECT
*
FROM comments c
JOIN replays r ON c.id = r.comment_id
ORDER BY r.id DESC
```

You should also watch out which is your primary entity.

- Do comments have replays?
- Do replays have comments?
- How many can each (relation) have?

Comment: no look .. count of replay for comment id one its tow replay
and count of replay for comment two its one comment
now the offset or series of replay for comment one be like this
1 and 2
and offset or position or series of replay of comment two must be 1
i need to get the offset or series

Comment: series or rank of replay